# Display a GoogleMap as Fragment inside of a libgdx Game

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'll make it quick in the hope anyone even still uses libgdx (all the tutorials on the topic are hilariously out-of-date)

What I want to do right now is create a GoogleMap and then insert that map inside my libgdx game so I can use the current position of the user on the map as gameplay-map.

For that I have created an Interface inside my Core-Project.

```
public interface MapInterface {
// Testmethod
int showMeTheMoney();
}
```

I give my Game a constructor that takes this interface as parameter and saves it inside a variable.

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
MyGdxGame gdx;
AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

    gdx = new MyGdxGame(new MapsActivity());
    initialize(gdx, cfg);
   }
}
```

I then initialize the game, giving the game a new instance of my Map. I can use interface functions; The map does exist or at least an object exists that allows me to use functions.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, MapInterface {

private GoogleMap mMap;


public void onClick(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AndroidLauncher.class);
    //To pass:
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}

@Override
public int showMeTheMoney() {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

And the MapsActivity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="500px"
android:layout_height="500px"
tools:context="com.mygdx.game.android.MapsActivity" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="Start Game" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Now, I am completely stumped as to how to display the damn map. How can I display the MapFragment inside my game?**

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create the interface that will display your map:

```
public interface MapsInterface {
    void openMaps();
}
```

now you should implement it on your android application and pass it to your gdxgame:

```
 public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements MapsInterface{
    MyGdxGame gdx;
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

            gdx = new MyGdxGame(this);
            initialize(gdx, cfg);
           }

         public void openMaps(){
                  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);
                  startActivity(i);
           }
}
```

Now in your game you just get the MapsInterface reference and call the openMaps(); method whenever you need to open the activity.

note: If you want only to use the current position of the user, you should go for getting the gps position instead using google maps.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. The problem with this code is that I wanted display the position of the player on the map, calculate a route for monsters to traverse and then place turrets on the map.
I did however use your exact code to get back to the MainActivity from the Victory/DefeatScreen, so it definitely works :)

I have since worked around the issue by taking a snapshot of the googlemap when the user presses "start game", via the onSnapShotReadyCallback provided by the googlemap. I simply save the path to the bitmap, give the game the path and load it as background texture.

Comment: Sorry for double comment: I then also get the "bounds" of the map-snapshot, convert the gps coordinates to pixelcoordinates and then use THAT to position everything. Works almost like a charm :)

Comment: I already use the routes API, but I still have to convert it to screen-coordinates, as it seems very complicated to use the actual map in a libgdx game instead of a snapshot.
As it stands, the GPS-bounds allow me to convert the coordinate-systems easily, the location-service gives me the current position whenever I need it. Seems unnecessary to revisit the issue at this point.